# Schengen visa for internship

Tags: germany, schengen, internship

I want to do an internship at an engineering company in Munich. As the duration of my stay is less than 90 days, I was told that I must apply for a uniform short-stay Schengen visa. But what should I choose in the form, as my main purpose of journey? (it includes Visit, Study, Business, Other, ...)

Because even though it is an internship, I am not sure if it counts as study, because it is not done as part of my formal coursework, and it is not done in a university (but an engineering corporation). Also it is a paid internship (in the 1000-2000 euros monthly bracket).

Should I choose Other and then state that my reason is internship? Or Study? Or Business?